# Why does AngularJS select all options instead of just the one clicked?

Tags: angularjs

In my AngularJS app I have an HTML form with some option elements, and when I change one option the other options also get changed. After reloading the page I can change individual values.

A function changeVariant is called on change and the values will be changed.

What causes this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Link points to http://webserver/Websites/saunadrome/reserveren/?arr=93#/stap/3 and does not work. If you want to provide example, make a plunker or something.

Comment: check scope variable name of all option is all are same.

Comment: Changed the link, now it goes to the correct page.

Answer (score 0):

This is the angularjs feature 2 way binding. if a scope variable is changed in controller the reference (object reference) value will also get changed in corresponding html pages. to restrict this you have to break the object reference. please check the below url to get some idea.

https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2863-breaking-direct-object-references-at-cache-boundaries-in-angularjs.htm